# Tabbed style actionbar and actions in one row

Tags: android

Is there a possible to use actionbar with tabs and the collapsed action menu in one row 
like in the image:
[image]

I would like to use standard android actionbar ,not the 3rd party lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is quite possible to do that without using a third party library. However, it will diminish your backward compatibility. What you can do, and what everyone else does, is use `ActionBarSherlock`.

Why do we need this third-party lib?

```
ActionBarSherlock is an extension of the support library designed to facilitate the use of 
the action bar design pattern across all versions of Android with a single API.
```

The benefit of this is:

A lot more users for the app

A stable, tested library at your disposal

http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Comment: The problem was when running my app in a narrow device , the actionbar was in 2 rows, one is the tab headers and one is empty with collapsed actions menu. I know actionbarSherlock, you convinced me I will try it.

Comment: +1 my answer please if you liked it

Answer (score 0):

When you use the standard actionbar, it does this only when there is a lot of space to do this. It will be like this when you are in a landscape phone or a tablet layout.

You cannot force the native actionbar to do this layout always. You can instead use a third party tab layout as a custom view. You can use this library. It is great. https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip